# next command in gawk not producing expected result

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to skip the whole first section of a bunch of tab-delimited text files. (I converted to comma-delimited for the sample data.) I just can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work:

CODE

```
gawk '
  /[^Country Of Sale]/ {next}
  /^Cloud Total/ {nextfile}
  FNR > 1 {$0 =  FILENAME OFS $0; print}
' OFS='\t' /path/to/files/*.txt > path/to/new_file.txt
```

DATA

```
"Start Date","End Date","UPC" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"Row Count","447","SKIP THIS LINE" 
"Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
"Cloud Total","1.36" "Sales Total","243.18" "Total Amount","244.54"
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
"Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
```

Also, I'd like to make the "Country Of Sale" line the header for all the files. But NR & FNR start counting at the beginning. How can I do that, given that "Country Of Sale" appears in a different line number in each file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you think `/[^Country Of Sale]/` is doing?  It probably isn't doing what you think it should.  Hint: one of the repeated blanks is superfluous.  (It just so happens that the blank is the only repeated character in that negated character class.)

Comment: well that gives me something more to look into. I'm just starting to learn (g)awk, just for a specific project. So I'm a complete noobie. Thanks.

Comment: another hint, drop the `[]` pair. .... and capturing a header that is on an unknown line number? I would process the file twice,`/Country of Sale/{hdr=$0}` being the first think you need. Good luck.,

Comment: Note that in your CSV data, `"Cloud Total"` does not start the line with `C`; it starts with a double quote.  I think you need something like: `gawk 'FNR==1,/Country Of Sale/ { next } /Cloud Total/ { nextfile } { print }' data`.  That lists just the AU line in the given data (and process the same file 3 times and you get 3 lines starting with AU).

Comment: In my actual data, it's tab-delimited with no double-quotes. I added those when I changed the tabs to commas, just to make it easier to look at in a blockquote.

Comment: I understand changing tabs to commas to aid visibility, I can't imagine why you'd add quotes though as that just obfuscates your question.

Comment: Why does your code include `$0 =  FILENAME OFS $0` if your expected output shouldn't have the file name at the start of each line? You're making this much harder than it has to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, `/[^Country Of Sale]/` probably isn't doing what you think it should. Hint: one of the repeated blanks is superfluous. (It just so happens that the blank is the only repeated character in that negated character class.)

What it actually does is looks for any character except one of `[ COSaeflnortuy]` (the square brackets are metacharacters) and jumps to the next line if it finds one.  For example, if the line contains a double quote or a comma, it will jump to the next line of input (because neither double quote nor comma is listed in the square brackets).

Note that in your CSV data, "Cloud Total" does not start the line with `C`; it starts with a double quote. Unfortunately, your regex searching for it insists that the `C` must be the first character.

I think you need something like:

```
gawk 'FNR==1,/Country Of Sale/ { next }
      /Cloud Total/ { nextfile }
      { print }' data
```

That lists just the AU line in the given data (and if you list the same file 3 times on a single command line, you get 3 lines starting with AU, so it works OK across files, in part because of the range `FNR==1,/…/`).

You should be able to take it from there.  You can make the patterns more restrictive (`/^"Country Of Sale",/` etc.) if you wish.  You can use `{ print FILENAME OFS $0 }` to print the line prefixed by the file name and an output field separator (a tab in your command line).

---

> This, and @Ed's suggestion too, both give *all* of the lines of data, instead of just what's between "Country Of Sale" and "Cloud Total".

This is what I get (on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, using a home-built `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1`):

```
$ cat data
"Start Date","End Date","UPC" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"Row Count","447","SKIP THIS LINE" 
"Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
"Cloud Total","1.36" "Sales Total","243.18" "Total Amount","244.54"
$ gawk 'FNR==1,/Country Of Sale/{next} /Cloud Total/ {nextfile} { print }' data data data
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
$
```

Given that I gave it the file to process 3 times, that's what I'd expect and appears to be what you'd want.

If you want the "Country Of Sale" heading line in the output, that can be added easily enough:

```
gawk 'FNR==1,/Country Of Sale/ { if ($0 ~ /Country Of Sale/) print; next }
      /Cloud Total/ { nextfile }
      { print }' data
```

And if you want the header only once even though it appears in many files, then:

```
gawk 'FNR==1,/Country Of Sale/ { if ($0 ~ /Country Of Sale/ && hdr_count++ == 0) print; next }
      /Cloud Total/ { nextfile }
      { print }' data
```

Comment: This must be tougher than I thought! This, and @Ed's suggestion too, both give *all* of the lines of data, in stead of just what's between "Country Of Sale" and "Cloud Total". I'll keep playing with various permutations of what you guys have taught me. Just the lesson on what [...] means was valuable. (That's the level of awk I am.)

Comment: Curious — see my update showing what I get.  I think it means you must have miscopied something, somehow, from the scripts.  From Ed's script, I get three lines per copy of the data file — the "Country Of Sale" line and the "Cloud Total" lines are also included in the output with his script.

Comment: And if you want the 'Country Of Sale' heading line in the output, there's a second update giving that.

Comment: hmmm. i just tried again. i literally cut-paste the script (and added my own "data" after the gawk program. and i get all of the lines.

Comment: Very, very curious!  What happens if you copy the data from my answer into a different file and process that?   Or the data from Ed's answer?  Have you checked the version of GNU Awk you're using?   What platform?  I'm not sure how line endings could be affecting this, but have you checked that they're correct for your platform?

Comment: Maybe delimiters? I copied my own test data & your script, as you suggested - worked! _***Orig***_ data is TAB-delimited & no ". Like this:

Start Date End Date UPC 4/2/17 5/6/17 SKIP THIS LINE
4/2/17 5/6/17 SKIP THIS LINE 4/2/17 5/6/17 SKIP THIS LINE
4/2/17 5/6/17 SKIP THIS LINE 4/2/17 5/6/17 SKIP THIS LINE
Row Count 447 SKIP THIS LINE 
Country Of Sale Total Total  Units1 Total Units2 Total C_F SPCU PCUT CPS USPS Total  Share EffSUBS ActSUBS
AU 0 139851331 139851331 195833.36 0.001400297 1170 1.36  1.36 91704.63 99430
Cloud Total 1.36 Sales Total 243.18 Total Amount 244.54

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154732/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-steve).

Answer (score 2):

`[...]` is a bracket expression which includes a list, set or range of characters. It does NOT contain a string or a negation of a string.

`[^Country Of Sale]` = `[^aCFelnoOrStuy]`

when you probably meant:

```
!/Country Of Sale/
```

which still isn't what you actually need. Try this:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  /Country Of Sale/ { f=1 }
  /Cloud Total/ { f=0; nextfile }
  f { print FILENAME, $0 }
' RAW/iTunes/iTunesMatch/*.txt > munched/iTunesMatch_TEST.txt
```

Look:

```
$ cat file
"Start Date","End Date","UPC" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE" "4/2/17","5/6/17","SKIP THIS LINE"
"Row Count","447","SKIP THIS LINE"
"Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
"AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
"Cloud Total","1.36" "Sales Total","243.18" "Total Amount","244.54"

$ gawk '
   BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
   /Country Of Sale/ { f=1 }
   /Cloud Total/ { f=0; nextfile }
   f { print FILENAME, $0 }
' file
file    "Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
file    "AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
```

If you have multiple input files and only wanted the Country of Sale line to appear once then one approach would be:

```
$ gawk '
   BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
   /Country Of Sale/ { f=1; if (NR==FNR) print FILENAME, $0; next}
   /Cloud Total/ { f=0; nextfile }
   f { print FILENAME, $0 }
' file file file
file    "Country Of Sale","Total","Total  Units1","Total Units2","Total C_F","SPCU","PCUT","CPS","USPS","Total  Share","EffSUBS","ActSUBS"
file    "AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
file    "AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
file    "AU","0","139851331","139851331","195833.36","0.001400297","1170","1.36","","1.36","91704.63","99430"
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. But this seems to give me *all* of the lines, rather than just the ones between "Country Of Sale" and "Cloud Total".

Comment: Then you copy/pasted the code wrong or your input isn't the same as you've shown us as that's not possible with the code in the answer. and input like you provided. I updated the question to show the script producing the output you wanted from the input you posted,

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @EdMorton @ @JonathanLeffler for giving me the necessary clues. What ended up working was using `/^Country Of Sale/{next}` & `/^Cloud Total/ {nextfile}`. Next, I'll go figure out exactly ****why**** this worked!

Comment: That cannot produce the output you posted from the input you posted.

Comment: The input I posted had double-quotes around the fields, and the delimiters were commas. In the original (non-simplified-for-S.O.) data, the delimiters were tabs, and there were no field separators. I don't know why that made a difference, but it seems it did. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No, it didnt. Neither the code I provided nor the code @JonathanLeffler provided made any assumptions about field separators or the presence of quotes in the input. Whatever the issue is it's neither of those.

Comment: well it gave the expected results, however it did. i'll go back and figure out exactly what happened after I finish what I've been doing. Thanks again for giving me the direction.